# Visual studio is restarting as I hit the required URL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am watching Kudvenkat asp.net mvc tutorial for bigginer part-8. And I have created EmployeeContext class which inherits from DbContext. And created it's object inside EmployeeController. but I am not getting the data from Database in EmployeeContext.

I have added the connectionstring as below.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext"
         connectionString="server=.;database=Kudvenkat;Integrated 
         Security=SSPI"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

before this it was like

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-4eUJ;Initial 
         Catalog=Kudvenkat;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

both are not working.

In one solution they have said delete the cache file in below but still no use

C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0

before deleting it was showing error something like VMDebugger.... something file cannot delete or found.

Code for model

```
namespace Kudvenkat.Models
{
    [Table("TblEmployee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Employee context code is already shared

Controller code is like

```
namespace Kudvenkat.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            //Employee employee = new Employee();
            //employee.id = 101;
            //employee.name = "Aditya";ee
            //employee.gender = "Male";
            //employee.city = "Pune";

            EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
            Employee employee =  employeeContext.employees.Single(emp => 
            emp.id == id);

            return View(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

Added setInitializer line at global.ajax with (null)

Database is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer, I have changed 3 things for that.

1. In connection string I have added **Integrated Security=SSPI** as it was Integrated Security= true earlier. but I don't know why do I need to do this?
2. Again In same connection string I have added 
   **providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"** as earlier it was like providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server". Can anyone tell what is the difference between this two.
3. This is important change too my Table fields and calss fields names were not same so I have changed my class field names same as DB name.